# Using DATEPART function in access SQL query with joined tables and aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access, datepart

I want to select the year and quarter parts of the date in a table rather than the whole date. I built the following query to achieve this:

```
SELECT Clients.ClientID,
       Sum(AccountVals.ValuationAmount) AS SumOfValuationAmount,
       Datepart("YYYY", AccountVals.valuationAmount) AS valYear,
       Datepart("Q", AccountVals.valuationAmount) AS valQuarter
FROM   (Accounts
        INNER JOIN Clients
          ON Accounts.ClientID = Clients.ClientID)
       INNER JOIN AccountVals
         ON Accounts.AccountID = AccountVals.AccountID
GROUP  BY Clients.ClientID,
          SumOfValuationAmount,
          valYear,
          valQuarter;
```

Although I have successfully used `DATEPART` in a simple select query the fact that this query is both an aggregate function and have linked tables is throwing me. Any ideas?

EDIT: I realise my query doesn't have any criteria which means it could be trying to aggregate the result from different dates so it can't show the dateparts. I tried adding something like `HAVING valYear = 2012 AND valQuarter = 3` but get the same error

Comment: This is because of the order operations are completed in: `FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY, SELECT, ORDER BY`, so for example when you reference `valYear` in the `GROUP BY` Access does not know what this is because it has not yet done the select and realised this is `Datepart("YYYY", AccountVals.valuationAmount)`. The same goes if you tried to reference the alias in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can use an alias in the `group by` clause, at least not without a subquery.  One solution is to repeat the exact expression in the group by, f.e.:

```
group by
        Clients.ClientID
,       datepart("YYYY", AccountVals.valuationAmount) 
,       datepart("Q", AccountVals.valuationAmount)
```

Comment: this doesn't help. Access now asks me to fill in a value for `SumOfValuationAmount`

Comment: `SumOfValuationAmount` should only appear once in your query, after the `as` clause.